# Как сделать проверку на текст в TeleBot?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Создаю РП бота для тг. Для своей практики. Мне надо сделать так , что бы при вводе любого слова из списка actions выводило то же самое действие из списка items. Но при этом делать проверку на каждое из действий не хочется. Можно обойтись циклом for ? Если да то как ?
Вот код:

```
actions = {
    'поцеловать',
    'обнять',
    'чмокнуть',
}

items = {
    'поцеловал',
    'обнял',
    'чмокнул'
}

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hello(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ну привет')
        
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message is not None)
def actionss(message):
    for i in actions:
        if message.text.lower() == i:
            for v in items:
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"{message.from_user.first_name} {v} {message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name}")
```

Comment: Чем именно поведение бота не устраивает вас?

Comment: он выдает 3 сообщения со всеми действиями, а мне надо с определенным. а точнее с тем, которое я написал. к примеру пишу я: обнять, а мне выдает все 3 действия 
... обнял ...
... поцеловал ...
... чмокнул ...
а мне надо что бы если я писал к примеру обнять оно выдавало только со словом обнял

Answer (score 1):

Занесём элементы в словарь и будем вытаскивать их из словаря когда надо:

```py
actions = {
    'поцеловать': 'поцеловал',
    'обнять': 'обнял',
    'чмокнуть': 'чмокнул',
}


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hello(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ну привет')


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message is not None)
def actionss(message):
    if message.text.lower() in actions.keys():
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                         f"{message.from_user.first_name} {actions[message.text.lower()]} {message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name}")
```